# Sort array of product codes by digits

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

I have products similar to:

125PPP
123ABC
124ABC
123DEF

How could I sort these products first by their digits (sizes) then in the case of the same digit - alpha?

I know I can split them up and sort an array of products by the digits, but what if 2 products use the same digits (2nd and 4th product in the example)?

Thank you.

Comment: you can do this by storing first three digit in array to and short according to them ... and get first three digit by `substr`

Comment: for this example you could just do a `sort` or if this is a string `$arr = explode(" ", $data); sort($arr);`

Comment: `usort` allows you to sort by custom ordering function.

Comment: @NullPoiner what about products with the same three digit code?
@Orangepill how would sort handle products with the same digits but different letters?
@Passerby how could I use `usort` specifically for this case? I've tried using `usort` before, but it's a little confusing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Best use natsort(). It orders alphanumeric strings the way a human being would, exactly what you need.

Answer (score -1):

```
$array = array("125PPP", "123ABC", "124ABC", "123DEF");
sort($array);
print_r($array);
```